# Using Dummy JSON data file in LWC JS

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, json, html

Hi i have a dummy JSON data file which i need to use in the JS of my LWC file can someone help me out for this...no sure how to do it,,,kindly help me out

Below is the Code :

```
{
    "copenStatus": [
        {
            "CDATE": "07/07/2020",
            "LDATE": "07/09/2020",
            "Acciuy #": "jngg",
            "Myweyru": "hggfhfb",
            
        },
        {
            "CDATE": "07/07/2020",
            "LDATE": "07/09/2020",
            "Acciuy #": "jngg",
            "Myweyru": "hggfhfb",
            
        },
        {
            "CDATE": "07/07/2020",
            "LDATE": "07/09/2020",
            "Acciuy #": "jngg",
            "Myweyru": "hggfhfb",
            
        }
    ]
}
```

JS :

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';


export default class testjson extends LightningElement {

}
```

HTml

```
<template>
    
</template>
```

kindly help me out for this!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [displaying data from dummy JSON file in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318059/displaying-data-from-dummy-json-file-in-lwc)

Comment: can you please just format my JSON i am not able to

Comment: I think its already well-formatted.

Comment: after using link you have given i am getting error as  "Expected a JSON object, array or literal.json"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON.parse() to convert the json to object. Note that your JSON file has multiple extra commas which I removed and minified it.

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';


export default class testjson extends LightningElement {
    property = JSON.parse(`{"copenStatus":[{"CDATE":"07/07/2020","LDATE":"07/09/2020","Acciuy #":"jngg","Myweyru":"hggfhfb"},{"CDATE":"07/07/2020","LDATE":"07/09/2020","Acciuy #":"jngg","Myweyru":"hggfhfb"},{"CDATE":"07/07/2020","LDATE":"07/09/2020","Acciuy #":"jngg","Myweyru":"hggfhfb"}]}`);

}
```